# Django ORM Subqueries

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm trying to figure out how to perform the following SQL query with the Django ORM:

```
SELECT main.A, main.B, main.C
FROM
  (SELECT main.A, MAX(main.B)
  FROM main
  GROUP BY main.A) subq
WHERE main.A = subq.A
AND main.B = subq.B
```

The last two lines are necessary because they recover the column C value when B is at a maximum in the group by. Without them, I would have A and the corresponding Max B but not the C value when B is at its max. I have searched extensively but cannot find an example that can construct this query using the Django ORM. Most examples use Django's Subquery class and show how to match the sub-queryset up with one column (so doing main.A = subq.A). But how do I match 2+ columns?

Edit:
Here is the model class:

```
class Tweets(models.Model):
    tweet_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tweet_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    candidate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    district = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    likes = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    tweet_text = models.CharField(max_length=560)
```

I'd like to group by "candidate" and "district", then find the tweet with the most likes. But I'd also like to know the "username" and "tweet_text" associated with that tweet that had the most likes.

Comment: Show us your model and explain what you want to do with it!

Comment: Added it in the edit.